# How do I clean the PCR of a Canon NX print engine?

Tags: laser-printer, cartridge

I recently bought a "new" Canon NX print engine (AKA "toner cartridge"). This is a classic print engine used in many laser printers in the 1990s.

The engine is new in the sense that it was sealed and packed, but it has probably been sitting in a warehouse for 20 years, so it shows some repetitive print defects that are probably because the primary charge roller was just sitting there in the same position for 20 years. So, I need to clean the PCR.

However, I need to get in there and do that without damaging anything. How can I do it?

Comment: I can't help, but just to say I wish you luck. I'm the other way round, rather than buying ink for an old machine I just throw the printer away with the cartridges & buy a new one - it's cheaper than the ink, a lot of times. My brand-new HP M477 £150. Replacement ink £550. No contest.

Comment: @Tetsujin, that strategy will work until the printer manufacturers start limiting the starter cartridges to just enough toner/ink to verify that the printer works.

Comment: @fixer1234 - they already do limit the 'freebie' ink - but at the moment I'm on break-even at least; this one ought to last me the next 10 years, my last one did. I'm low-output, so inkjet just dries up between uses. Laser just keeps on going ;-)